# Interchange Lebesgue-Integral and infinite Sum with $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1)}-\chi_{[n+1,n+2)}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1)}-\chi_{[n+1,n+2)}$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function. Have I calculated the following statements correctly? $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure.
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n \, \mathrm{d}\lambda=  1,
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f_n \, \mathrm{d}\lambda=0.
$$

Comment: Yes you have computed it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out!